# Two Google calendars on my Android (HTC)?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I can access my personal [Google calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar).

Can I also access my work Google calendar (we use [Google Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps))?

Can I

- Merge these two, but not share my personal calendar with work mates?
- Set it up not to receive work emails?

**EDIT:**
HTC Desire on Android 2.1

Comment: Which HTC phone do you have, and which Android version is it running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can add the eMail adress from your GApps account via

Settings > Accounts & Synchronisation > Add Account

Then enter your credentials and you can access your accounts eMail, contacts and calendar without automatically sharing information from your private calendar with your colleagues.

But you need to watch out which account you use creating new calendar entries from now on.

After that you need to open your calendar application and press Menu > Calendar > Select the calendars you want to see.

If you don't want to see your work eMails you can easily decide which items you want to synchronize with your device.

Merging the calendars is not really necessary since you can view many different calendars in the calendar application.

Comment: I shared my work calendar and added to my personal one. But I can see only `busy` if in my personal calendar. If I can make it work that I can see details for the calendar item on my mobile it would be great. I cannot see the shared calendar from my mobile :-(

Comment: This is something with your sharing settings for your work Google Calendar. You need to make a few settings there. You might find help on this over at SO.

Comment: SO would not be the right venue for asking for help with Google Calendar. Rather, [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) would be the place to ask.

Comment: True, but providing an answer here is ok IMHO.